# What's up with suggested edit no. 35?

Tags: support, editing

Well, I was just trying to see what was the first suggested edit. So I tried, `http://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1`. Okay that didn't work nor did 0. Doing some bisection the earliest suggested edit I could find was 31.

Okay SE could be starting that counter from 30. But what's up with 35 where's it? (Just curious ;))

(This is the only site I can currently test this on because of being able to see deleted posts.)

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, the counter is distributed over *all* the review tasks.  That being the case, if the first suggested edit review is number 31 (as you posit) that just means that the *first* thirty review tasks *weren't* suggested edits.

Of note, you can find review tasks for *close votes* with counters of [30](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/close/30) and [35](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/close/35), but none exist under counters 31 through 34.

I could probably prove this more decisively by close examination of the data dump for the site (or, y'know, getting an actual SE developer to answer this question), but I can't be bothered right now: I'm more than happy with ad-hoc speculation. :)